# Changing account on iPad and now can't download updates

Tags: ipad, icloud

Our iPad was initially set up for my wife but has now been passed on to my son. As part of this we made an iCloud account for him and changed to the iPad to use it.

The problem is that the apps on the iPad were downloaded on my wife's account, which is no longer logged in and none of them will update.  I do not know the password for this former account.

Is there any way to move the app to the new account? One app in particular cannot simply be uninstalled and reinstalled or he'll lose his progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
There is no way to transfer app ownership.

For the future make sure to set up [Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/HT201060) which will allow all members of the family access to the same apps [with some few exceptions, not all apps are shareable this way], but this will not enable transfer of existing app data from one member to another in such a way as to preserve game progress.
You will have to continue to use the account it was initially registered to, to continue using the data linked to that account.
Without Family Sharing, it is possible to have apps on one device that were technically 'purchased' by other accounts, but each will require the login details of that account to make changes.

If you have lost the password for the old account, start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Comment: We have Family turned on, but this does not seem to solve the problem of downloading updates?

Comment: Family Sharing enables the *initial download* & therefore ownership by each family member. It's not retrospective, it cannot transfer ownership after the fact.